# Running OSX in VirtualBox on a Bootcamped Mac pro with Win7

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox, iso-image

I have bootcamped my Mac Pro with Windows 7 64-bit. I'd like to be able to run OSX in a a VM via VirtualBox. I tried following the steps listed here: http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows without much luck. I get *System config file '/com.apple.Boot.plist' not found* when trying to boot the image suggested in the tutorial. I have the OSX Install cd but when I try to boot from it I get *FATAL: No bootable medium found! System. halted.* In the VirtualBox log I am getting:

`00:00:03.082 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed

00:00:03.084 Guest Log: BIOS: CDROM boot failure code : 0004

00:00:03.084 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from CD-ROM failed

00:00:03.085 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Hard Disk 0 failed

00:00:03.087 Guest Log: No bootable medium found! System halted.`

So it looks like the OSX install DVD is not being recognized, it also includes Windows executables for installing drivers and software when the system has been bootcamped so I am wondering if this is preventing the system from recognizing it as a bootable disc. When I explore the disc in Windows Explorer I only see the Windows files and no Mac files. Any ideas on how to get VirtualBox to see the disc as bootable? Or possibly rip the OSX image from the DVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can create an iso of the install DVD in OS X.  Go to the Disk Utility and select the DVD, click New Image in the toolbar, and choose "DVD/CD Master" as the format.  After it's complete, change the .cdr extension to .iso and I think VirtualBox should recognize it...